# Is there anything wrong with using T & F instead of TRUE & FALSE?

Tags: r, r-faq

I noticed that using `T` and `F` instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE` in functions in R gives me the same results. Of course, `T` and `F` are more concise, yet, I see `TRUE` and `FALSE` being used more often.

I was wondering whether there is any difference between the two? Is there anything wrong with using `T` and `F`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`T` and `F` can be re-defined, but `TRUE` and `FALSE` are reserved words and cannot be re-defined.

```
> TRUE <- 1L
Error in TRUE <- 1L : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
> FALSE <- 0L
Error in FALSE <- 0L : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
> T <- F  # yikes, this would be hard to debug!
```

Personally, I sometimes use `T` and `F` when I use R interactively, but I *never* use them in production code or packages.

Comment: Note that in S+ it was the opposite--`T` and `F` were the reserved words and `TRUE` and `FALSE` the variables with defaults.  I wish it were that way in R, but c'est la vie.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman  I believe it was partially the fault of the genetics community, who for some reason like to use "T" for something else.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Interesting.  Seems like they profited from a pyrimidine scheme.

Comment: You're not allowed to use `T` and `F` in cran packages - so if you're going to submit to cran, you'll have to change them anyway.