# Extracting chunks from a matrix by columns

Tags: r, matrix

Say I have a matrix with 1000 columns. I want to create a new matrix with every other `n` columns from the original matrix, starting from column `i`.

So let say that `n=3` and `i=5`, then the columns I need from the old matrix are `5,6,7,11,12,13,17,18,19` and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using two `seq()`s to create the start and stop bounds, then using a `mapply()` on those to build your true column index intervals. Then just normal bracket notation to extract from your matrix.

```
set.seed(1)
# using 67342343's test case
M <- matrix(runif(100^2), ncol = 100)
n <- 3
i <- 5

starts <- seq(i, ncol(M), n*2)
stops <- seq(i+(n-1), ncol(M), n*2)
col_index <- c(mapply(seq, starts, stops)) # thanks Jaap and Sotos

col_index
[1]  5  6  7 11 12 13 17 18 19 23 24 25 29 30 31 35 36 37 41 42 43 47 48 49 53 54 55 59 60 61 65 66 67 71 72 73 77 78
[39] 79 83 84 85 89 90 91 95 96 97

M[, col_index]
```

Comment: You can drop the `as.numeric` imo and wrap the `mapply`-call in `c()`. On a sidenote: it is better to use `TRUE` instead of `T`.

Comment: What is the logic between T vs TRUE, I thought T was a reserved character?

Comment: @NateDay see: [*Is there anything wrong with using T and F instead of TRUE and FALSE?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256639/is-there-anything-wrong-with-using-t-and-f-instead-of-true-and-false)

Comment: Of course wrapping it with `c()` makes the `SIMPLIFY` argument redundant

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is based on the fact that R uses index recycling:

```
i <- 5; n <- 3
M <- matrix(runif(100^2), ncol = 100)
id <- seq(i, ncol(M), by = 1)[rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = n)]
M_sub <- M[, id]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would write a function that determines the indices of the columns you want, and then call that function as needed.

```
col_indexes <- function(mat, start = 1, by = 1){
    n <- ncol(mat)
    inx <- seq(start, n, by = 2*by)
    inx <- c(sapply(inx, function(i) i:(i + by -1)))
    inx[inx <= n]
}

m <- matrix(0, nrow = 1, ncol = 20)
icol <- col_indexes(m, 5, 3)
icol
[1]  5  6  7 11 12 13 17 18 19
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using `outer`.

```
c(outer(5:7, seq(0L, 95L, 6L), "+"))
[1]  5  6  7 11 12 13 17 18 19 23 24 25 29 30 31 35 36 37 41 42 43 47 48 49 53 
[26] 54 55 59 60 61 65 66 67 71 72 73 77 78 79 83 84 85 89 90 91 95 96 97
```

To generalize this, you could do

```
idx <- c(outer(seq(i, i + n), seq(0L, ncol(M) - i, 2 * n), "+"))
```

The idea is to construct the initial set of columns (`5:7` or `seq(i, i + n)`), calculate the starting points for every subsequent set (`seq(0L, 95L, 6L)` or `seq(0L, ncol(M) - i, 2 * n)`) then use `outer` to calculate the sum of every combination of these two vectors.

you can subset the matrix using `[` like `M[, idx]`.