# columns removed while removing duplicated rows in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
dat <- data.frame(year = c(1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988),
             a = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 350, 350, 350, 430),
             p = c(60, 90, 80, 75, 95, 600, 600, 600, 330),
             y = c(1, 1, 12, 11, 12,  13, 13, 13, 20))
```

if `y` is duplicated, then only keep the `y` with the highest `a`. 
If duplicated `y` have the same `a`, then  keep `y` with the highest `p`. 
If duplicated `y` have the same `a` and `p`, then simply remove them. I did this:

```
dat %>% dplyr::arrange(y, a, p) %>% dplyr::group_by(y) %>% 
dplyr::filter(a == max(a)) %>% dplyr::filter(p == max(p)) %>%
distinct(a, p, y)
```

But how do I retain my `year` column here?

Comment: add `.keep_all = TRUE`  to `distinct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can specify `.keep_all = TRUE` in `distinct`.

You are selecting your rows based on several conditions which you could combine in less lines of codes with `arrange` and `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  arrange(a, p) %>% 
  slice(n())
```

Or:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  arrange(desc(a), desc(p)) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

Further if you'd like to select the highest value given a weight you could use `top_n`:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  top_n(1, a) %>%
  top_n(1, p) %>% 
  distinct(y, a, p, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

The last two approaches will keep the year 1985 for y = 13, wheras the first approach keeps the year 1987. You might want to specify which year (max or min) you want to keep for duplicated values.

Comment: It is better to use `TRUE` instead off `T`, [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18256639/2204410).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that.